# Files tries to search everytime I try to rename file when downloading

Tags: files, downloads, browser, filemanager

Recently when I have been trying to download a file from Firefox (and to my knowledge, other web browsers as well), everytime I try to rename a file, it tries to search my files instead, and doing this also results in it not downloading at all, regardless of whether the name of the file actually ended up changing

Any help to fix this would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: To be clear you are accessing some location with Firefox and using that app downloading a file? Have you tried other browsers or is this just a guess? How and when are you trying to rename the file? Your question needs a lot more details.

Comment: @David, I've looked online and this seems to be an issue with other browsers as well. I'm trying to rename the file right after hitting the download button in the box that appears to pick where to download, I can rename it fine after its downloaded, but it's a lot more convenient to do it before it's actually downloaded

Comment: OK 2 things. 1. Please post the link so I read read about the issue with other browsers. 2. What is the exact info you are using when trying to rename are you trying to specify a directory as well as a name?

Comment: @David, I found someone else having this problem with Brave (https://community.brave.com/t/cant-change-name-of-a-file-when-download/415385),and I try to rename the file name, not the extension, but it greys out the selection tab for it in the bottom right corner. I'm send the files to downloads, try to, at least.